# How to detect in C++ if exe is running inside cygwin or cmd

Tags: c++, c, winapi, cygwin

I'm writing C++ application using Visual Studio.
I want to detect in runtime if application is running in cygwin or cmd.

I need it because I want to print coloured text, and it's done differently in cmd and differently in cygwin.

Comment: There is no standard way to detect this. I would just add a command line parameter to specify which type of formatting to use

Comment: Well. That's what I'm doing at the moment. But I was hoping for some more user friendly way.
From what I find out for now it seem like GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo is falling on cygwin, and working on cmd.
But running it causes strange behaviour on cygwin.

Comment: The question suggests that these are the only two options, but it is entirely possible to start a console mode executable from Explorer.

Comment: In this case if you run if in explorer it's same as if you run it by entering filename in cmd.
Detecting that may be useful in other cases, but that's different question for other time.

Comment: If you do `NtQueryObject(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), ObjectNameInformation, ...)`, you will see that for cygwin output it always looks similar to this: `\Device\NamedPipe\cygwin-0123456789abcdef-pty0-to-master`

Comment: But if you only need it for Win10, then you could just enable `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` with [SetConsoleMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode), then you can use the virtual terminal sequences also for cmd output.

Comment: Thx @ssbssa for info. It feel hacky, but it works. `NtQueryObject(cmd,ObjectTypeInformation,info,ir,&ir);` on my computer is giving `"Key"` in cmd and `"File"` in cygwin.
If you post it as answer I will mark it as solution.

Comment: `HANDLE cmd = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
unsigned long ir = 0;
NtQueryObject(cmd, ObjectTypeInformation, NULL, 0, &ir);
PPUBLIC_OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION info = (PPUBLIC_OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION)(malloc(ir));
NtQueryObject(cmd, ObjectTypeInformation, info, ir, &ir);
if (info->TypeName.Buffer[0] == 'K' && info->TypeName.Buffer[1] == 'e' && info->TypeName.Buffer[2] == 'y'){
 /*cmd*/
}
else if (info->TypeName.Buffer[0] == 'F' && info->TypeName.Buffer[1] == 'i' && info->TypeName.Buffer[2] == 'l' && info->TypeName.Buffer[3] == 'e'){
 /*cygwin*/
}
else{
 /*dont know*/
}
free(info);`

Comment: I find out it's also possibel by checking enviroment variables "TERM" and "TERM_PROGRAM".
Cmd doesn't set them. But Cygwin does. And they can be read in C++ using function std::getenv().
`if( std::getenv("TERM_PROGRAM")==std::string("mintty") ){/*cygwin*/}else{/*cmd or something else*/}`